# Async validator of type Observable never ends

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-reactive-forms

I'm doing a web application in Angular 8 and Firebase Firestore. I have a form with just one input to enter an identification number (as string). I want to validate if there is a user with this ID or not.

I have tried to implement an async validator. It checks if the ID exists, if it's not, should return an error to display a message in the template.

```
constructor(
    private clientService: ClientService,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.clientForm = fb.group({
      identificationNumber: ['', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(11)
      ], CustomValidator.validateUser(this.clientService)]
    });
  }
```

The async validator:

```
static validateUser(clientService: ClientService): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl):
      Promise<ValidationErrors | null> |
      Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
      if (control.value.length !== 11) {
        return of(null);
      } else {
        return control.valueChanges.pipe(
          debounceTime(1000),
          switchMap(_ =>
            clientService.getClientByIdentificationNumber(control.value)
              .pipe(
                map(client => return client ? null : {notfound: true}),
                catchError(err => return of(null))
              )
          ),
          first(),
        );
      }
    };
  }
```

The method from the service to get the user:

```
getClientByIdentificationNumber(identificationNumber: string): Observable<Client> {
    return this.afs
      .collection(
        'clients',
        ref => ref.where('identificationNumber', '==', identificationNumber)
          .limit(1) // Just get one
      )
      .snapshotChanges().pipe(
        // flatMap() will return a single Client
        flatMap(actions => actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Client;
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;

          console.log('getClientByIdentificationNumber'); // Called several times

          return {id, ...data};
        }))
      );
  }
```

The method `getClientByIdentificationNumber` from the service is called over and over again, it never ends.

My goal is to check if there is a client with that ID and return the error, handling the Observables correctly to prevent leaks and leaving open subscriptions by mistake.

Comment: why do you add control.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(1000)??

Comment: @SadidKhan I'm doing that to let the user type the entire string without activating the validator immediately, reducing the http calls.